# Stripping Audio From Vob Files through command prompt

Tags: audio, wav, vob

What we need to do is either, extract the audio from a group or singular Vob video file and convert it to a .Wav format. Now the process of actually extracting the audio and converting it can be done from a third party application however this application has to be activated from a batch or c# script. The media we are retrieving the vob files from always comes from the CD drive and will always be placed in the same folder location once the conversion is complete.

In shot I need a program or script that can be activated remotely to extract and convert vob files to .WAV.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only install ffmpeg on Windows and put in cmd this command:

```
ffmpeg -i [VOB_file_route].VOB  [WAV_file_output_route].wav
```

And that's all, just works.

Answer (score 0):

To do somthing like this you will need to use VLC and cmd they work togeather well and will allow you to strip video and audio from a file easily